# WebRTC change default (500kbps) bandwidth NodeJS - Kurento Media Server (KMS)

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, webrtc, bandwidth, kurento

I am using Kurento Media Server for my WebRTC project, I've been following the tutorial [one2one-call](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-one2one-call).

Everything is okay until I'm using the media constraints of 640x360, as the bandwidth required by this constraints fits within the default bandwidth of KMS i.e. (500kbps), but as I increase the video resolution it demands more bandwidth and the video starts to pixelate, on the other end.

What I have tried till now

- using **setMinVideoSendBandwidth**, **setMaxVideoSendBandwidth**, **setMinVideoRecvBandwidth**, **setMaxVideoRecvSendBandwidth** on webRtcEndpoints
- adding "**b=AS: 5000**" to the client side offer SDP before setting it as local description and sending to server (**edited kurento-utils.js**).
- changing bitrate in **MediaElement.conf.ini** at server configurations

I'm using kurento-utils.js at client side for inititaing RTC object, creating and answering offer.
As I said above I tried to add **b=AS: 5000**, for that I edited the kurento-utils.js.

I'm not sure if this required but my KMS runs on AWS and the Application server is hosted locally and on remote VPS.

Thanks in Advance!